# How does a ClickOnce app properly specify DPI Awareness and GdiDPIScalingForceDisable to ensure GDI Scaling is Off?

Tags: .net, winforms, clickonce, gdi+

Per this link:

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/05/19/improving-high-dpi-experience-gdi-based-desktop-apps/

Microsoft set it up so that Users OR the company IT guys OR the app developers can specify whether to use GDI Scaling or not.  And that they set it up so that if any of the three requests to NOT do GDI Scaling, then that wins.  Perfect.  But how do we, as ClickOnce app developers, specify GdiDPIScalingForceDisable?

Most instructions give you things to stick in either the Manifest or in the App.config or both.  However, to date we've never seen those work.  Rather, there have been other things that have told us for ClickOnce apps, we need to make a call to `SetProcessDPIAware();` when we start up our app.  Is there a similar call we should be using to `SetProcessToDisableGdiScaling();` or some such???

Or has someone gotten the typical Manifest / App.config settings to work in their ClickOnce app??

Any guidance greatly appreciated,
   Brian

Comment: Does it fail with `.Net FW 4.7.2+`?

Comment: Not being able to use a manifest to specify dpiAware is a fundamental limitation of ClickOnce.  But it is what you actually like, right now you can be sure that it is *false*.  The odds that this will ever change are quite low, if they improve the situation then they'll make it part of the CO manifest, which is in your control.

Comment: @HansPassant  But it is NOT false... if the user clicks Off the "Fix scaling for apps" option, then it seems GDI Scaling is getting turned on... because some of our Metafiles are getting partially scaled resulting in cropped graphics.  So, we are hoping there is some way to force GDI Scaling off programmatically rather than manifest (just like we can switch on DPI Awareness programmatically instead of manifest... we have it set to "System" DPI Aware).

Comment: @Jimi, It does fail with .NET Framework 4.8.

Comment: Yes, I mean, with .Net 4.7.2+ and setting the DPIAwareness in `app.config`. I understand that ClickOnce should handle the `app.manifest` and this setting (may) make it fail (*may* because I believe I was told that from 4.7.2+ the issue was solved). I remember you asked about Metafiles before. I, personally, don't have issues with Metafiles (GDI+ and dual mode) and DPIAwareness. Maybe you should work on that.